# How to check the Notification Received Status from Firebase in my Server

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I have setup push notification service with Firebase, I'm sending notifications with the help of REST API, notification are received by different clients at different times based on their token.

There can be different reasons when a user will not be able to receive the notifications for e.g. he don't have Internet connection.

**So I need the status from client side that either the  notification is received on the device or not or it is in pending state? with the notification details**

I need to get this info and save it in my server. How this can be achieved?

Comment: Are you looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?